# How to add a date Label in JSQMessagesViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a date label to the JSQMessageViewController and im implementing the correct method, but nothing is showing up. Here is my code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let message: JSQMessage = self.messages[indexPath.item]

    return JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter.sharedFormatter().attributedTimestampForDate(message.date)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to override`collectionView:layout:heightForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath:` as well.

Looks like the default value would be `0.0` according to the [source](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/532eb513a06881b562bc0b9e2fa9d00111285eb3/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m#L665).